# wordpress custom query order posts by most recent comment

Tags: wordpress

As title says it, I hope you could help me out with custom loop that retrieves the post with the most recent activity on it (meaning last commented post).

Basically, for my homepage I'm trying to retrieve one post from each category. Not just any post but the one with most recent approved comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but maybe something like this can get you started:

```
function get_heated_posts()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $IDs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_comments ON wp_posts.ID=wp_comments.comment_post_ID ORDER BY wp_comments.comment_date DESC", ARRAY_N);
    return $IDs;
}
$heated = get_heated_posts();
$query = new WP_Query(array('post__in'=>$heated, 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    //POST HTML
endwhile;endif;
```